# Access a hash with a dynamic variable - getting Parse error Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

I have a hash in my route defined as:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    signedServices: {
      lyft: false,
      uber: false,
      postmates: false,
      doordash: false,
      caviar: false
    }
  });
},
```

In my handlebar view, I'm iterating through all my services and outputting the value of the hash:

```
{{#each (signup-services-array model.signedServices) as |serviceName|}}
  {{model.signedServices[serviceName]}}
{{/each}}
```

However, I keep running into the error:

```
Parse error on line 108:
...        {{log model.signedServices['lyft
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'
```

**What does this error mean and how do I resolve it?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access keys in objects in HTMLBars this way. You should use `get` helper instead:

```
{{get model.signedServices serviceName}}
```

Comment: Is the get helper built in or something I have to implement?

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_get or if you use older version then use https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-get-helper